# How do I use enumerations with XML-RPC and C#?

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, enumeration

I'm using the Cook Computing XMLRPC framework in C#. I'm calling a remote function that expects an int. I want to use an enumeration in the client code instead of just calling the function with the digits hard-coded in the function parameters.

The code compiles successfully, but during testing an XmlRpcUnsupportedTypeException is throw. The message states that my enumeration cannot be mapped to an XML-RPC type. The enum is as follows:

```
public enum Codes : int
{
    Installed = 903,
}
```

I have a feeling there is something simple I am overlooking, but can't put my finger on it so I'm here shining my Bat signal into the clouds!

Comment: ...and the answer shows it was indeed simple. D'oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tried explicit casting?
(int)Installed

MSDN:

> The underlying type specifies how much
>   storage is allocated for each
>   enumerator. However, an explicit cast
>   is necessary to convert from enum type
>   to an integral type. For example, the
>   following statement assigns the
>   enumerator Sun to a variable of the
>   type int by using a cast to convert
>   from enum to int:
>
> int x = (int)Days.Sun;

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly cast it to an int:

```
int code = Codes.Installed; // doesn't work.
int code = (int) Codes.Installed; // works.
```